# Whats wrong with my email regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I have following regex:

```
var emailRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"
```

And when I am trying to type:

```
asd@asd
```

It matches. Why?

Comment: Because that is a valid email address.

Comment: @Juhana, can you explain?

Comment: According to the specs, a TLD by itself is allowed in an address. In practice nobody has such a public address, but it's still valid.

Comment: The problem is that the backslashes need to escaped as you're using the string to create regex. Either use regex literal or escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

Email services don't have to be connected to any domain.
Following emails are all correct:

- cezary@localhost
- cezary@192.168.1.100
- cezary@domain
- cezary@com

See more under "Valid email addresses": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

So if you want to allow only public emails, try other regexp :-)

Answer (score -3):

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) answer your question
Try this:

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
alert(validateEmail("test@gmail.com"));
```